# why DNNClassifier doesn't accept Sparse features, but LinearClassifier does

Tags: tensorflow

*tf.estimator.DNNClassifier* doesn't accept sparse feature columns such as *categorical_column_with_hash_bucket*. It can only accept dense columns which always needed to be wrapped with indicator_column.

```
category_column = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(key, hash_size)
tf.feature_column.indicator_column(category_column)
```

*tf.estimator.LinearClassifier* on the other hand can accept *categorical_column_with_hash_bucket* directly.

```
tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(key, hash_size)
```

According to this [tf source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py)

*Sparse features can be fed directly into linear models. They behave like an indicator column but with an efficient implementation.*

I wonder what such efficient implementation is there in Linear as against DNN which restricts DNN to only accept dense columns.

Answer (score 0):

Linear classifiers and other "shallow models" are picky about sourts of inputs that they can accept. `categorical_column_with_hash_bucket` is a hacky way of squeezing an variable size input or a enormous sparse vector into a nice fixed size numeric representation.

In DNN terms we therefore should take a look at 2 cases to replace `categorical_column_with_hash_bucket`. One for strings and one for sparse vectors.

In case of strings we can project a string into fixed size representation using an embedding layer. It allows a reacher, higher dimensional representation and, most of all, it is trainable. Embedding can be trained along with the main part of network.

When it comes to sparse vectors things become tricky. First of all, DNNs don't shine when it comes to low dimensional data and sparse vectors typically have very little information (low entropy). Because of that sparse data can be easily overfit by a DNN that has millions of parameters. Nevertheless, you can still try using embedding layer for your case. Otherwise, stick to linear models - they are much more robust and adopted to sparse vectors.